# .NET create anonymous type from another type but modifyng some fields

Tags: .net, serialization, anonymous-class

I have some class with "complex" objects like Enumerators, Lists and others. I need to construct the same anonymous object from instance of this class.
However, I need to convert all enumerators, bools, Lists and some others types in a way I want.

```
public class MyClass {
   public string Str1 {get;set;}
   public bool B1 {get;set;}
   public MyEnum EnumVal {get;set;} 
}
```

So the instance of this

```
var cl = new MyClass() { Str1 = "Some rand", B1 = true, EnumVal = MyEnum.Value1 } ;
```

should be converted into some anonymous class with values:

```
{ Str1 = "Some rand", B1 = 1, EnumVal = 1 }
```

I thought about having two classes like `MyClass` and `MySimplifiedClass` and use `AutoMapper`, but in future `MyClass` could be extended and I do not want manually add properties to `MySimplifiedClass`. Instead I have defined rules how some of types should be converted (these are `booleans, enumerators, Lists`).

Comment: And why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: I have to save this class into specific file format. The client who reads this file has these specific rules already defined. So they do no tread bool as true/false, but they need 1 or 0. They have their own rules how Lists/Arrays should look like. There are already existing methods to create this specific file format, I just need to pass there my class. If I pass MyClass instance it will fail. I need to serialize to another class or anonymous class that fits the rules.

Comment: What format exactly? Why can't you just save serialize from original data applying the rules without using intermediate anonymous objects? Are those methods extensible? Can you show some [mre]? Usually fiddling with dynamic type creation is the worst option.